# unwrapping errors with subdivision

Tags: modifiers, uv

i have a problem unwrapping. I have a model, which is simple in my opinion, but am sort of new at this, and i just can't seem to unwrap it perfectly. the uv layouts are wrong, and all stretched out. [image]

Plus every time I unwrap, I keep getting the error "subdivision surface modifier needs to be first to work with unwrap" and I didn't even use any modifiers in my model.
[image]
Please help. it will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the messy uvs in the upper right because you need to place more seams so Blender knows how to flatten that area for the UVs. You are most likely getting that error message about subdivision ebcause you have "use Subdivision Surface checked as shown in the attached picture. This will display as long as this is checked and you don't have a modifier attached.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Besides Zak's pointing to Subdivision error ... I think your issue lays also in the model itself. You have connected faces in a wrong way in this areas ... enable Face Orientation overlay or Face Normals in X-Ray to see better what is going on there.

[image]